# How to convert SinkRecord to JSON string?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Imagine `myAPICreate` requires a JSON string.

```
public void put(Collection<SinkRecord> collection) {
        for (SinkRecord record : collection) {
            JSONObject recordJson = toJSON(record.value());
            String recordJsonString = recordJson.toString();

            myAPICreate(recordJsonString);
        }
    }
```

`toJSON` is a helper I have defined which just takes the record and returns a JSONObject.

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject()
  .put("a", record.getString("a"))
  .put("b", record.getString("b"))
  .put("c", record.getString("c"));
```

I feel like I might be doing a lot of redundant work here. Is it necessary to have the code in `put` convert it to JSON or is there a way to use the converters so that `record` already comes in as JSON or a JSON string? Then I can just pass `myAPICreate(record.value().toString())` without having to manually do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you [create a `SinkRecord`](https://kafka.apache.org/22/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/sink/SinkRecord.html), you have a key & value schema w/ a key and value Object. Those objects should be [`Struct` instances](https://kafka.apache.org/22/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/data/Struct.html) that must be created with the matching `Schema`

In the Connector configuration, you would then use `JSONConverter` (or other converter) to get the serialized output

Comment: Hey thanks! But could you elaborate or point me towards some sample code that demonstrates what you mean? Am I supposed to use methods like `converter.toConnectData` and `deserialize`?

Comment: No. Converters should ideally not be used within a Connector task. You use Structs and Scehmas to build SinkRecords https://kafka.apache.org/22/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/sink/SinkRecord.html  and https://kafka.apache.org/22/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/data/Struct.html

Comment: Sorry, I am still not 100% sure what you mean. Can you simplify more? Are you saying that in the sink task's `put` method, I don't need to do any manual JSON conversion, and that the JSONConverter already handles that, so I can just `.toString()` the SinkRecord's value if it has a schema? I already have a custom transform that modifies the schema and value before it is placed in the topic the sink connector reads from. So if my sink connector reads from this topic that was given a schema, the resulting sink record should be able to use this schema to turn it into a JSON string?

Comment: Where does "have your SinkRecord wrap a SchemaAndValue object" need to happen? I currently do source -> transform (apply schema and change value) -> topic -> sink.

Comment: When you create a SinkRecord, you have a key & value schema w/ a key and value Object. Those objects should be `Struct` instances that must be created with the matching `Schema`

Comment: Ok, so I currently use a custom transform similar to this: https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-transform-common/blob/master/src/test/java/com/github/jcustenborder/kafka/connect/transform/common/ExtractNestedFieldTest.java This makes me assume that my custom transform (which does the schema/struct stuff) would handle what you mentioned, then I can just use JSONConverter in the sink connector config, and then it's good to go by the time it gets used as a `SinkRecord` in the sink task's `put`.

Comment: Since the API call expects a JSON string, it sounds like StringConverter is what I will actually need in the end coming out of the topic to the sink. `The string converter stores and retrieves messages in JSON string representation on disk at the Kafka broker.
Use this converter to bridge between FTL applications and Kafka applications that use JSON strings without attached schemas.`. Thanks for all the insight, I'll give it a shot!